# Can't define the right margin-top's %

Tags: css

I have a series of containers, all set to height 100% starting from 'body'.

I set 'article':

```
article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The height works fine taking half of its parent's (or screen, doesn't matter) height, but the margin-top is definitely not 25%, more like three times it.

Live link: http://no-plans.com/temp/wp-tobias/wordpress/?p=51

Disclaimer: still dirty stylesheet, there might be inherited conflicts but I can't find any. I also tried to resize and put the margin to other parent divs, same issue.

Comment: Try resizing your window horizontally, the margin is relative to the width too.

Comment: That's right: margin percentages are relative to container's width: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties.

Comment: I had no idea, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, `margin` percentages are relative to container's width: http://w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties.

You can solve by absolute positioning and `top` (here the percentages are relative to container's height).